# Designing Validation for Editable asp.net WebControls

Tags: asp.net, validation, inheritance, web-controls

In a fit of annoyance with Asp.Net's Validation Controls (disjointed, verbose, awkward) I decided to see whether I could create a series of Input Controls that each carry their own validation methods and properties.

One of my design criteria is to allow my Validation properties to show up in VS intellisense as Tag attributes along with the rest of the control's properties.

My first thought was to create a base class that inherits from WebControl and implements the new properties and methods, but without multiple iheritance that would mean an inability to also derive from, say, TextBox.

That seems to mean either

- inheriting from each WebControl (TextBox, DropDown, etc.) and (re)coding common Validation properties and methods for each of my control classes (with or without interface that seems wasteful), or
- coding a base class (say ValidatedInputControl) once and finding a way to implement individual WebControls (textbox etc) in classes that inherits from ValidatedInputControl. I suspect that means rendering etc., or,
- finding some other pattern/design that gets there more efficiently

So, I am looking for suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do dumb questions always look even dumber a few hours later...

For any who are interested, its not so hard to figure out after a break and some dinner.. polymorphism 101 and some .Net magic...

Create a concrete class (MyBaseClass) with the members you want all the derived controls to inherit. Inherit this base class from the **CompositeControl** class.

Now create the individual controls you want (myTextBox, myDropDown, etc.) inheriting from MyBaseClass - these individual control classes are now of types **MyBaseClass and CompositeControl**.

So, inside each individual control class (say MyTextBox) you can now instantiate the appropriate native control (TextBox) and manage it like any composite control, but it also has access to MyBaseClass members.

duhh... all in all just CompositeControl business as usual.....